# Include CASE in Insert/Values/Output block

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @INSERTED_BOOKS table (
  BookId int,
  Image varbinary(max),
  Preview varbinary(max)
)

MERGE Books_Destination AS d
USING Books_Source AS s
ON 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (Author, BookCategoryId, Title)
VALUES (s.Author, s.CategoryId, s.Title)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, s.Image, s.Preview
INTO @INSERTED_BOOKS;
```

I need to integrate a converstion for s.CategoryId to d.BookCategoryId:

```
case 
  when CategoryId = 1 then 2
  when CategoryId = 5 then 8
  when CategoryId = 14 then 6
  when CategoryId = 22 then 9
```

My problem is how to integrate this CASE into my insert code.

Answer (score 2):

With a condition like `ON 0=1` you are forcing an "always INSERT" so why not just insert?

```
INSERT Books_Destination (Author, BookCategoryId, Title)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.Image, INSERTED.Preview INTO @INSERTED_BOOKS
SELECT Author, 
     case 
     when CategoryId = 1 then 2
     when CategoryId = 5 then 8
     when CategoryId = 14 then 6
     when CategoryId = 22 then 9
     END, Title
FROM Books_Source;
```

But to MERGE anyway.. put the case into the source definition so you can use it if, say, you want to UPDATE later and have one CASE only

```
MERGE Books_Destination AS d
USING (
   SELECT Author, 
     case 
     when CategoryId = 1 then 2
     when CategoryId = 5 then 8
     when CategoryId = 14 then 6
     when CategoryId = 22 then 9
     END AS BookCategoryId, Title, Image, Preview
FROM Books_Source
) AS s ON 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN 
  INSERT (Author, BookCategoryId, Title)
  VALUES (s.Author, s.BookCategoryId, s.Title)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, s.Image, s.Preview INTO @INSERTED_BOOKS;
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with your code. Image and Preview are not being inserted so I am getting the error "the multi-part identifier could not be bound" for INSERTED.Image, INSERTED.Preview. s.Image and s.Preview does not work either.

Comment: The second version, with Merge, also has sintax errors. In fact, as you said, I do not need the MERGE. This was just me trying to make this work.

Comment: Try it without the OUTPUT clause first. And is this for the MERGE or INSERTED? Also, where do they come from anyway because Books_Source does not have these columns so I assume they have to come from Books_Destination

Comment: I need output because I will use those columns values to do something else with other tables.

Comment: Just test with no OUTPUT *first*. I also fixed syntax (an extra `)`) was there

Comment: Where do Image and Preview *come from*? They are not from Books_Source based on your example code

Comment: Both Image and Preview are from  Books_Source but they are not in Books_Destination. I will use them to populate a third table named Files that is why I am using OUTPUT

Comment: @MiguelMoura then you need a MERGE. INSERT won't allow that. I also change the MERGE to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
MERGE Books_Destination AS d
USING Books_Source AS s
ON 0 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT (Author, BookCategoryId, Title)
VALUES (s.Author, 
(Case s.CategoryId When  1 Then 2
                 when 5 then 8
                when 14 then 6
                when 22 then 9
                else NULL
                End)
, s.Title)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, s.Image, s.Preview
INTO @INSERTED_BOOKS;
```

Comment: there is extra comma after `as category id`

Comment: I did not use two commas. The error "incorrect sintax near 'as' " happens even with one comma